# Android FATAL EXCEPTION at android.arch.lifecycle on Kotlin lang

Tags: java, android, kotlin, lifecycle

i just try to convert my old android project in java to Kotlin and also add google Android Architecture Components to my project :

```
// LifeCycle Google Lib
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0-alpha5"
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha5"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha5"
// Room Google Lib
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9"
testCompile "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:1.0.0-alpha9"
```

and then when i run app faced with this errors :

```
E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.043 26169-26169/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.122 26174-26174/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.200 26180-26180/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.284 26187-26187/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.366 26193-26193/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.450 26197-26197/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.530 26206-26206/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.605 26210-26210/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.696 26214-26214/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
08-19 17:26:11.775 26221-26221/? E/dex2oat: Failed to create oat file: /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex: Permission denied
```

and this :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: ir.adrapanadevs.aya, PID: 26090
                                                                 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method iterator()Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap$ListIterator; in class Landroid/arch/core/internal/SafeIterableMap; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap' appears in /data/app/ir.adrapanadevs.aya-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                     at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:101)
                                                                     at android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner.attach(ProcessLifecycleOwner.java:154)
                                                                     at android.arch.lifecycle.ProcessLifecycleOwner.init(ProcessLifecycleOwner.java:100)
                                                                     at android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider.onCreate(LifecycleRuntimeTrojanProvider.java:36)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                                     at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5217)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4812)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4752)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1424)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5485)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

how to fix that?
**thanks**

Comment: Did you try clean and rebuild

Comment: yes i do clean and rebuild but not fixed.

Comment: Just change your Lifecycle version to alpha 9 like room ORM.

Comment: @Karo thanks , i already update that and every things is OK .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Updating LifeCycle Libs to Alpha 9 Problem Solved.